# Insufficient Access Right on "Without Sharing" Class

Tags: apex-sharing

I'm trying to insert Sharing records via apex for the object "SBQQ__Quote__Share".
The class that inserts the record uses "without sharing", but when i to insert the record i receive the error:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id: []

This code works for other objects by the way..

i'm not adding the entire code as it is unnecessary, so here are the relevant parts:

```
public without sharing class OpportunityLookupsShareManager { 
public static void manageAccessToObject(sObjectType shareObject, sObjectType shareType,string oppFieldApiName, Map<String,Boolean> sharingMap) {
    Set<Id> opportunityIdSet = new Set<Id>(); 
    List<SObject> objectList = new List<SObject>();
    objectList = (List<SObject>)Type.forName('List<' + String.valueOf(shareObject) + '>').newInstance();
    List<SObject> sharedToInsertList = new List<SObject>();

    // ... Some logic here ...
        if (!sharedToInsertList.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                System.debug('sharedToInsertList: ' + sharedToInsertList);
                insert sharedToInsertList;
            } 
            catch  (DmlException ex) {
                system.debug(Logger.getException(ex));
                Trigger.New.get(0).addError(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

in the debug logs i see:

> sharedToInsertList: (SBQQ__Quote__Share:{AccessLevel=Edit, ParentId=a0x0Q0000002zwEQAQ, UserOrGroupId=00558000001ODmLAAW, RowCause=Manual})

Anyone knows what might cause the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dana Griff ,
This kind of error is basically coming due to sharing the inserted record back with the owner of the record who has full permissions on it already.
 for reference:

1) https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008z1JIAQ

2) https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206576&type=1

3)  [Why am i getting INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY error on code that worked before summer 13 update?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12772/why-am-i-getting-insufficient-access-on-cross-reference-entity-error-on-code-tha)

4) [INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/90184/insufficient-access-on-cross-reference-entity-insufficient-access-rights-on-cro)

hope it help you.

Comment: i didnt even think about the option that the user already has sharing, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert/updating the data in SBQQ__Quote__Share object. it seems, user dont have permission to access this object. could you please confirm the user access? please check the profile

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ZnJaQAK

Comment: its a "without sharing" class, so the profile access doesn't matter.
already found the answer, thank you :)