# Insert failed. First exception on row first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Tags: apex, profile, manual-sharing

A limited access profile user creates a lead. there is a certain action flow which uses appointment object to book appointment on lead for which i have to extend create and read access to this profile. Now the backstory is, as the appointment gets booked it automatically gets assigned to an owner and i want the assigned owner to continue from there but because of the limited access of records the lead owner is unable to see appointment record even if he created the appointment record so, i dedcided to extend him the read access through manually sharing record using apex even if the profile is having create and read access but due to owner assignment, it is not visible. so while sharing through manual sharing using apex, i am getting the above error - INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY. Any solution?

```
    Map<Id, Id> finalSAtobeshared = new Map<Id, Id>();
    Set<Id> allSAcreatedId = new Set<Id>();
    List<User> allUserIds = new List<User>();
    Set<Id> finalUserIds = new Set<Id>();
    
    for(ServiceAppointment sa: newAppointment){
        allSAcreatedId.add(sa.CreatedById); 
    }  
    
    allUserIds = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'Test Profile' AND Id IN :allSAcreatedId];
    for(User u: allUserIds){
        finalUserIds.add(u.Id);
    }
    System.debug('Final User Ids: ' + finalUserIds);
    for(ServiceAppointment sa: newAppointment){
        if(finalUserIds.contains(sa.CreatedById)){
            finalSAtobeshared.put(sa.Id, sa.CreatedById);
        }
    }
    System.debug('Final List of SA: ' + finalSAtobeshared);
    List<ServiceAppointmentShare> insertList = new List<ServiceAppointmentShare>();
    ServiceAppointmentShare appShare = new ServiceAppointmentShare();
    for(Id i: finalSAtobeshared.keyset()){
        system.debug('Id>>>'+i);
        appShare.ParentId = i;
        appShare.UserOrGroupId = finalSAtobeshared.get(i);

        System.debug('Check: ' + UserInfo.getUserId());
        appShare.AccessLevel = 'Read';
        appShare.RowCause = Schema.ServiceAppointmentShare.RowCause.Manual;  
        insertList.add(appShare);
    }
    
    insert insertList;
    Database.SaveResult[] sr = Database.insert(insertList, false);
    for (Database.SaveResult saveResult : sr) {
        if (saveResult.isSuccess()) {
            System.debug('Record Succesffully created '+saveResult.getId());
        } else {
            for (Database.Error error : saveResult.getErrors()) {
                System.debug('Record Failed'+error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Contemplate the exact DML that causes this error. If this happens in the Apex, add the section with the DML to your question. Explain why the executing user *should* have necessary access rights.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. It is essential that you include relevant code snippets or flow details, including those related to sharing control (e.g. the specific type of flow, any advanced settings for the flow, or details of the Apex class including `with` or `without sharing` specification plus how your "manual sharing" is implemented).

Comment: @FelixvanHove I have added the code with which I am trying to give the read access to the lead owner who is booking the appointment throught the flow and having create and read access to the appointment object but as soon as the flow is trying to create the appointment it assigns the appoinment to a particular owner which is not the lead owner so even if the record is createdby this user it is not able to see it because of owner assignment. so i am giving it manual access through code  but i think it is contradicting somewhere as the lead owner already have access to object but not to record.

Comment: You need to add the class declaration so we can see if it is `with` or `without` sharing.

Comment: @PhilW I have added without sharing to class, still the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

From your text I'd expect the ID of the executing user to be assigned to UserOrGroupId. However the code assigns the ID of the creator of the appointment. This is likely to be (at least sometimes) the owner of the appointment.

We can't create manual sharing for a user, who is already the owner of the record. For this sort of a problem see e.g. [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252704/insufficient-access-right-on-without-sharing-class).

(According to shown code you insert `insertList` two times; I assume this code was set up temporarilly for debugging reasons.)